# Rails nested attributes "no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer" for has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, associations, nested-attributes

I've following are the Model codes.

**user.rb**

```
  has_many :teams, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :companies, dependent: :destroy

  after_create :create_tables!

  def create_tables!
    companies.create!
    Team.create!(user_id: self.id, company_id: Company.where(user_id: self.id).first.id)
  end
```

**company.rb**

```
belongs_to :user    

has_many :teams, inverse_of: :company, dependent: :destroy
has_many :users, through: :teams

accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams
```

**team.rb**

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :company, inverse_of: :teams
```

Following are my Controller codes

**companies_controller.rb**

```
def new
    @company = current_user.companies.new
    @company.build_teams
end


def update
    current_user.companies.first.update_attributes(company_params)
    respond_to {|format| format.js}
end

  private

  def company_params
    params.require(:company).permit(:name, :about, :problem, :solution, :logo, :url, :email, :phone, :category, :started_in,
                                    teams_attributes: [:position, :admin])
  end
```

**In views**

```
<%= form_with model: @company, method: :put do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :teams_attributes, @company.teams.first do |team| %>
              <%= team.hidden_field :admin, value: true %>
              <%= team.text_field :position, placeholder: 'Eg: CEO', class: 'input' %>
          <% end %>
<%= f.submit 'Next' %>
<% end %>
```

When i try this in rails console it works and saved in db, in views params are also passing good. Its below

[image: params passing in browser]

But in views it says

```
TypeError in CompaniesController#update no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `f.fields_for :teams` instead of `f.fields_for :teams_attributes`

```
<%= form_with model: @company, method: :put do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :teams, @company.teams.first do |team| %>
    <%= team.hidden_field :admin, value: true %>
    <%= team.text_field :position, placeholder: 'Eg: CEO', class: 'input' %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.submit 'Next' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Hi @H Dox, i had changed the attributes. Now the new params are...https://ibb.co/nKQu4K. Now both company name and position are not saving to database.

Comment: The params seem to be correct to me. Could you paste the query log from rails console?